# Is there a way to turn off impersonation for ISAPI extensions?

Tags: iis-7, impersonation

Is there a way to configure IIS7 to use worker process identity instead of authenticated user when running ISAPI extension?

Comment: This might be useful reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525338%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: @NathanC It is, thanks, I suppose the same applies to IIS7?

Comment: Yeah, it applies.